# Running a Command, that will not terminate upon closing terminal

Tags: terminal, nohup

I am trying to work with a remote device that I login to using SSH, the device uses MQTT for communication, and I want to be able to log that remotely without keeping a terminal open with the command running. Currently my command I run is shown below, but it cannot be ran without keeping a laptop connected with the terminal running.

I have read about using solutions like (nohup "command" &), but I have been unable to factor that into the below code.

```
mosquitto_sub -v -u Test -P Test123 -t '#' | while read -r line ; do
        echo -e "$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") $line"
done | tee -a MQTT.txt
```

So to summarize I want to be able to run the above code, and detach the process from the terminal so that it will continue to run without the terminal being connected, which I believe is possible using nohup, but I also still need to log the messages to a local file so they can be reviewed later. How would I change the above code so that it is possible to do that?

Comment: You could use `screen`.

Answer (score 1):

You can write

```
nohup bash -c 'mosquitto_sub -v -u Test -P Test123 -t "#" | while read -r line ; do
        echo -e "$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") $line"
done | tee -a MQTT.txt'
```

However what you really want is `screen` or `tmux`. These program will allow you to run the command, logout and after login just connect to old "already closed" terminal.

---

Very basic screen session in your example will look like this:

```
screen

mosquitto_sub -v -u Test -P Test123 -t '#' | while read -r line ; do
    echo -e "$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") $line"
done | tee -a MQTT.txt

# Hit "Ctrl-a d", it will detach the screen
```

Now you can close the terminal and logout, after login again run `screen -R`.